# Allowing certain scripts to set inline styles

Tags: security, styles, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm securing my page using a csp headers. I set both `X-Content-Security-Policy` and `X-Webkit-CSP`. to the following value:

```
default-src 'self';
object-src 'none';
frame-src 'self' *.youtube.com;
style-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com;
script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com;
report-uri /csp_report
```

Everything loads fine, but I get tHe following error in chrome. I have yet to test it in other browsers.

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content 
Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com".
```

referring to a line in a script on the current domain, that's trying to insert some HTML containing inline styles. Is there a way to allow scripts that I have whitelisted usin script-src to do this? I'm getting the same error for jquery, hosted on ajax.googleapis.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked `'unsafe-inline'`. Resources that I allowed to load can use inline styles by doing this:

```
style-src 'unsafe-inline'
```

Comment: unsafe-inline isn't a "solution" as it just circumvents the security policy for EVERYONE which is the same as not having one in the first place.