# How to add 'unsafe-inline' keyword to run inline javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, unsafe-inline

I'm learning  javascript and trying to run some inline javascript code. I'm using the [electron quick start guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/) and the code works fine before I try to add some inline javascript.
Here's my *index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log("Hello World"); // <-- this is the line causing problems
    </script>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to load the webpage with the *console.log("Hello World")* added, I get the error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-m/hGOmrcpR2CLf5ZFUFQux1kBtD2znXvM4R5xVpagmI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

The error message tells me that I can add an *'unsafe-inline* keyword. Exactly how do I do that?

I have tried searching for examples, like [this example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760874/allowing-certain-scripts-to-set-inline-styles), or [this guide on content-security-policy.com](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/). But all the examples just tells me to add 'unsafe-inline' to the content security policy, without actually showing how that's done.

Comment: Show your server-side code.

Comment: Instead of trying to fix inline javascript, why not create a script file a link that instead?

Comment: @SuperStormer, I'm using this quick start guide for electron: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/
So I don't really have any server side code.

Comment: @Reyno, having the script in a separate file is my eventual goal. But I would like to start by simply having the script inline with the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `unsafe-inline` by changing your meta tag to the following. However I'd suggest keeping it the same and just load JS via a separate file since changing the tag adds some security risks. It's called **unsafe** for a reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log("Hello World"); // <-- this is the line causing problems
    </script>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
  </body>
</html>
```